# Chapter 3, Mission 3 - Lost the ability to use scout drone

Tags: anno-2070

There are several side quests where you have to use the scout drone on your ship to scan underwater areas. On my ship I do not have the "scout drone" in my slot. I cannot buy this item either. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Select your Ark. EVE will sell you one for $5,000.

Answer (score 1):

Under the building menu select, tech and build a carbon production chain.  Then build submarine yard also, in tech class.  A submarine yard will allow you to build a T38, which has a scout drone.

Comment: edit: submarine yard can make t38 which has scout drone and you can get oil under the tycoon tab

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your arc provides a sea dragon for this misson.